# Getting 'Not Applicable 'in WSO2 Identity Server 4.0.0

Tags: wso2, xacml3, wso2-identity-server, wso2-esb

I am working on this link in WSO2 IDS 4.0.0.

http://malalanayake.wordpress.com/2013/02/13/authentication-and-authorization-with-wso2esb-and-wso2is/

> I develop the service as per above link   In WSO2 IDS 4.0.0 Server
>   evaluate the policy through the Tryit.
>
> I entering same data and   click on TEST EVALUTE.
>
> Showing an error ” No applicable policies were found for the request”.
>
> Can you anyone explain me where did i mistake.

Here i am sending my XCML Policy file.

```
<Policy xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:core:schema:wd-17" PolicyId="EchoServicePolicy" RuleCombiningAlgId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:rule-combining-algorithm:first-applicable" Version="1.0">
   <Target>
      <AnyOf>
         <AllOf>
            <Match MatchId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:string-equal">
               <AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">testRole</AttributeValue>
               <AttributeDesignator AttributeId="http://wso2.org/claims/role" Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:subject-category:access-subject" DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string" MustBePresent="true"/>
            </Match>
         </AllOf>
      </AnyOf>
   </Target>
   <Rule Effect="Permit" RuleId="Rule-1">
      <Target>
         <AnyOf>
            <AllOf>
               <Match MatchId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:string-equal">
                  <AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">read</AttributeValue>
                  <AttributeDesignator AttributeId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:action:action-id" Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:attribute-category:action" DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string" MustBePresent="true"/>
               </Match>
            </AllOf>
         </AnyOf>
      </Target>
   </Rule>
</Policy>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The possibility is that this 'testUser' is not in the role of 'testRole'. You can go to Configure --> Users & Roles in management console and check this.

Comment: HI Pushpalanka,Thank you it's working , but from ESB Tryit side it giving an error as **<TryitProxyError h:status="SOAP envelope error" xmlns:h="http://wso2.org/ns/TryitProxy">org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: The input stream for an incoming message is null.</TryitProxyError>**  and here is my git url    https://gist.github.com/anonymous/7352372 .Please guide me how to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

Can you show us the XACML policy and the request. 
This error simply means that the none of the active policies in the IS are applicable to the received request.

Comment: Hi Pushpalanks,First thank you for replay,i configured XACML policy according to above given url,,Any way i updated the my Question with XACML Policy,Could you please lookinto onces